# Purpose of "postgres" Unix user

Tags: postgresql

To access psql, I have to first login to another Unix account

sudo su - postgres

then I can do

```
postgres@linux ~ $ psql
psql (9.1.10)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```

However, I don't understand why the postgres Unix account (when I do sudo su - postgres) is necessary.  What's wrong with just running "psql" from my original Unix account?

And do the postgres Unix and command line share the same password?

*I'm pretty new to Linux/postgres, so feel free to give fundamental explanations

EDIT: another question:
What's the difference between

```
postgres=#
```

and

```
postgres-#
```

Comment: You don't need to use sudo, you can start `psql -U postgres` to log in as the postgres user.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm asking why the postgres Unix account is needed in the first place.  Why can't I go directly to the "postgres=#" command line from the user@linux I was originally using?

Comment: You can do that, and a horse with no name told you how to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> However, I don't understand why the postgres Unix account (when I do sudo su - postgres) is necessary. What's wrong with just running "psql" from my original Unix account?
>
> And do the postgres Unix and command line share the same password?

The Postgres user can't log in and only reads/writes to whatever it owns, unless you create it or configure your computer otherwise otherwise.

And therein lies the reason for it to be around: security. It's not *technically* required (as an example, homebrew on OSX will use your own username), but best practice -- especially on a server.

Comment: Is the only purpose to make sure that you don't modify anything other than postgres files?

Comment: And not giving login or shell access to Postgres, yes. One word: security.